# Get Firebase cloud function snapshot children data

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Spent all day on this. I'm really struggling with Typescript and Firebase Cloud Functions.
I want to 1) monitor the 'purchases' node of my database. When a new purchase is made, I want to 2) sum all the user's purchases and then 3) send that to my CRM (sendinblue).

I can get #1 the monitoring done. And I figured out #3 how to send the information to my CRM. It's #2 the middle step I'm having trouble with. I can't figure out how to get the array of information from the `.once` method into a single value. I just want to end up with a number like 8.97 to send to my CRM (that would be 1.99 + 2.99 + 3.99, FYI).

My database looks like this:

```
{
  "1": {
    "price": 1.99,
    "product": "Product A",
    "subscriptionExpiryDate": 1569445492
},
  "2": {
    "price": 2.99,
    "product": "Product B",
    "subscriptionExpiryDate": 1575556926
},
  "3": {
    "price": 3.99,
    "product": "Product C",
    "subscriptionExpiryDate": 1587990802
}
```

Here is my code:

```
exports.purchaseTEST3 =
functions.database.ref('/users/{userID}/purchases').onUpdate((change: any, context: any) => {

  const userRef = change.after.ref

  let totalPurchases = 0

  userRef.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot: any[]) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

      const key = childSnapshot.key
      const childData = childSnapshot.val()

      totalPurchases = totalPurchases + childData

      console.log('TEST3 info:', key, childData, totalPurchases)
      // ^ gives "TEST3 info: 123 { price: 456 } 0[object Object][object Object]"
    })
  })
})
```

The console logs look like this:

`TEST 3 info: 0[object Object][object Object][object Object] 3`

so I know I'm getting the info. I just don't know how to parse it (or whatever the term may be).

Am I going about this incorrectly? I've looked [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58312876/add-a-property-to-a-created-object-firebase-functions) and [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) and a dozen other places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit confused as to your end goal... but I assume that you want access to each individual child node (either the key, the value or both) from each child. If that is the case, I would add childData of each child to an array inside the foreach loop.

Outside the foreach loop, create an array object, then in the loop, add childData to the array.

```
exports.purchaseTEST3 =
functions.database.ref('/users/{userID}/purchases').onUpdate(async(change: any, context: any) => {
try{
  const newArray: Array<string> = [];
  let totalPurchases = 0

  const CS = await userRef.once("value"); // this will wait for this function to resolve before continuing. CS will be a snapshot object
  CS.forEach(function(childSnapshot) { // I do not use ForEach very often so this is untested syntax but the jist is there

      const key = childSnapshot.key // this will be the master key, in this case 1, 2, or 3
      const price = childSnapshot.child("price").val();
      const product = childSnapshot.child("product").val();
      const ExpireDate = childSnapshot.child("subscriptionExpiryDate").val();
      newArray.push(product); // this will be the only thing accessible outside this forEach loop

      totalPurchases = totalPurchases + price // You might have to convert price from a string to a number 

      console.log('TEST3 info:', key, product, price, ExpireDate, totalPurchases)
    })
    console.log("product 1: " newArray[0]);
    console.log("product 2: " newArray[1]);
    console.log("product 3: " newArray[2]);
...
}
catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        return err;
}
})
```

Please note this is untested, so some edits might be required but the general thought process should hold up.

Once the loop finishes, you can access any of the nodes from the array, provided you know the order in which they were accessed. To fix that problem, look into "OrderByChild".

I would also look into using async and await in your cloud functions instead of returning a task (.then(function....)). Google's typescript documentation is lacking, but feel free to respond if you want more details on that. I personally liked this youtube video from Firebase Summit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tResEeK6P5I&t=1101s   The video gets relevant to async await just before the 18 min mark.

Good luck!

EDIT:

I think I see the issue, you need to dig another level deeper into your snapshot. as written in your example, childData is going to be a snapshot that includes both a new key and a new value. Try this:

```
const price = childSnapshot.child("price").val();
const product = childSnapshot.child("product").val();
const ExpDate = childSnapshot.child("subscriptionExpiryDate").val();
```

Inside the loop. The rest of my comment still stands, but this should get you that extra level deeper. The string argument for child needs to match your key exactly. I updated the above code sample to reflect this change.

Comment: Yep, that's it. That's what I was missing. I didn't add the `.val()` to the end of the object to get the object's value. Thanks!!

Comment: And yes, I'd like to know more about how to use their Typescript functions. I have read all the documentation I can find on their website, and I could not find the answer to my question above. I've also watched Doug Stevenson videos. That's actually where I got most of my code. If you have more ideas on where to go to get more sample code and ideas, I'm all ears!

Comment: @PhontaineJudd The Doug S videos are great, and mostly why I picked Typescript when I started with Firebase, however sine those videos were posted, they have kind of forgotten about Typescript. The Youtube clip I referenced in the answer is a great supplement to the Doug Vids, and that is where most of my Firebase specific typescript knowledge has come from. I will update the code snippet in my answer above to use ASYNC AWAIT which makes the code much easier to read and understand. If you are going to be doing a lot of FB Typescript, I strongly recommend you get a good handle on async early

Comment: Updated the code above... NOTE the **async** keyword after onUpdate. I also added a try catch block. Having said all of this, you technically shouldn't have to access the database again, you have everything you need in the snapshot.after object that you get passed when onUpdate is called (in this case, you called it change.after). you could instead get that data using this command:```change.after.child('1').child('price').val();``` Stacking child calls like this should work in most cases

Comment: I'm coming from a Swift background, so all this Typescript is kind of a foreign language to me. I appreciate the links and the information you've provided. I guess I just need to dive in and start learning `async await`. [sigh]